# Reading and parsing xml file in Spring Project

Tags: java, xml, spring

I want to parse xml file in spring project. Can anyone provide direction for this?

This xml file will be used to load various fields which are required to be validated for each jsf page.

I want to use this xml to be read through document build factory or any generic function present in the spring

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
```

I want to validate a page for specific values which are defined in this xml. So I need to parse this xml file as we do in simple java program using `DocumentBuilderFactory`

Comment: do you want to parse a generic XML file, or do you want Spring to read your XML configuration file and instantiate your beans?

Comment: you want to parse any .xml file, or you want to parse the spring configuration xml files?

Comment: Or a Java properties.xml file?

Comment: @Bozho i want to parse any xml file

Comment: @Sean this is not a java properties xml file

Comment: What kind of vague question is this? Just stopped short of downvoting. Please can you explain your question more clearly?

Comment: @Vish OK, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: @Sean Basically i want to validate a page for specific values which are defined in this xml.so i need to parse this xml file as we do in simple java program using DocumentBuilderFactory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is much too vague, many different scenarios are possible.

However, I thing you should take a look at the Chapter [14. Marshalling XML using O/X Mappers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/oxm.html) from the Spring reference. Perhaps you will find the answer there.

---

Ah, more info in the Question. So the XML contains properties, although it is not in the Java properties XML format.

OK, then I guess I'd [write a BeanPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp) that uses [Commons / Config](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) under the hood to read the properties from XML. You should probably copy what the [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer) does, to a certain extent.

Comment: i have new question on [AspectJ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110948/using-aspectj-on-websphere)