# using Aspectj on Websphere

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, websphere, aspectj

we are using Aspectj compile time loading  in Spring source tool suite..when we are trying to deploy this project on websphere server ,we are getting following exception .this  project work fine on the tomcat server..is there is some problem with libraries as AspectJ compiler is are already there in Spring Source Tool.

```
Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions
(1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: 
Property 'exceptionProp' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:   org/aspectj/runtime/internal/AroundClosure.linkClosureAndJoinPoint(I)
Lorg/aspectj/lang/ProceedingJoinPoint
```

Comment: Did you changed the class loader order to: parent last?

Comment: @Ralph no we have not done that

Comment: try to change the class loader order of your web module to: "parent last"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WebSphere ships with it's own version of AspectJ Runtime.  It is installed in:

base_${version}/lib/aspectjrt.jar

Flipping the class loader order from 'parent first' to 'parent last' won't work -- you'll have to take a different route.

1. Create a Shared Library (in the WebSphere Admin Console)
2. Add your version of AspectJ to this Shared Library
3. Create a new Classloader for your application or server and attach this classloader to it.

Instructions on how do to this can be found on IBM's website:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tcws_sharedlib.html