# classpath in websphere application server for aspectj agent

Tags: java, websphere, classpath, aop, aspectj

I am working on a java aspectj agent which measues the response time of all methods.

I followed below steps to test the aspectj on linux development environment.
ajc -source 1.7 .java -outxml -outjar ResponseTime.jar

java -javaagent:/home/hadoop/aspectj1.7/lib/aspectjweaver.jar -cp "$CLASSPATH:code:ResponseTime.jar:/home/hadoop/aspectj1.7/lib/aspectjrt.jar" Application

i have websphere application server in my productions server and when i tried above vm arguments my Load time weaving was not happening.

i need help on how we can set classpath for "$CLASSPATH:code:ResponseTime.jar" in web sphere..

Comment: Possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110948/using-aspectj-on-websphere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Login to WebSphere Admin console using admin user
2. Follow below steps to update ClassPath and VM arguments of server

a.  Select the Servers -> Server Types -> WebSphere Application Server -> Resource -> Java and Process Management -> Process definition

c   Add absolute path of Aspectj jars to the classpath  text area window 
    .jar
     aspectjweaver.jar
     aspectjrt.jar

d.  Add below comment into the Generic JVM arguments  tab 
    -javaagent:aspectjweaver.jar -Dorg.aspectj.weaver.Dump.exception=false -

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following into generic JVM arguments (Servers->Server Types->WebSphere Application servers->(selected server)->Java and process management->Process definition->Java virtual machine):

```
-javaagent:/full/path/to/aspectweaver.jar
```

This will use ascpectj compiler built into WebSphere. If your ascpectj compiler is newer, try with the procedure described on [using Aspectj on Websphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110948/using-aspectj-on-websphere)

Comment: thanks @Miljenko.  please correct me if i wrong. -javaagent should be agentweaver and not ResponseTime.jar.. Command which i used to create ResponseTime.jar is as follows...   ajc -source 1.7 ExecuitonTimeAspect.java -outxml -outjar ResponseTime.jar

Comment: Got it now, yes, you have to give full path to aspectjweaver.jar, and ResponseTime.jar is instrumented JAR that is part of your enterprise application.

Comment: Don't forget to update your answer, @Miljenko with that correction

Comment: @Miljenko - I cannot add ResponseTime.jar to the enterprise application as of now. I need to add this jar externally to the application. for that reason i have asked about classpath of websphere.. In normal desktop you will execute it using below command                                                                      java  -javaagent:C:\\aspectj1.7\lib\aspectjweaver.jar -cp ".;code;Demo2.jar;C:\\aspectj1.7\lib\aspectjrt.jar" Main